# ¿Cómo obtener coordenadas en un hilo aparte al principal?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo este código el cual consiste en un hilo nuevo aparte del hilo principal, una vez abierto el hilo, busco obtener las coordenadas cada 5 minutos, el código corre sin bloquearse cada 5 minutos, pero no entrega las coordenadas, siempre se va por la Exception. La hacer el debugger a la excepción aparece un error (imagen adjunta) del cual no tengo la menor idea.

Como lo puedo corregir?

Alguien me puede colaborar por favor

Gracias

Este es error de la excepción y el código del nuevo hilo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class nuevo_hilo extends Service implements LocationListener {

private Thread workerThread = null;
private Context thisContext=this;


Location location;
LocationManager locationManager;
double latitude, longitude, lat, lon;

public nuevo_hilo() {

    lat = 0.0;
    lon = 0.0;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    if(workerThread == null || !workerThread.isAlive()){
        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){

                for (int i = 1; i>=0; i++){

                    try{

                        Thread.sleep( 30000 );

                        if ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisContext,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            Toast.makeText(thisContext, "Permisson not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        try {

                            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)thisContext.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

                            boolean isGPSEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER );

                            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                                lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 10, (LocationListener) thisContext);
                                Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                                lat = l.getLatitude();
                                lon = l.getLongitude();
                            }

                        }catch (Exception e){

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }


                    }catch (Exception e){

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                }

            }
        });
        workerThread.start();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hay funciones que necesitan ser ejecutadas en un looper, para eso Pon Looper.prepare() antes de ejecutar el codigo no se cuales seran pero puede ser el toast. luego dale Looper. end o algo asi que finalize.

Comment: En tu código no tienes un Handler, estas haciendo uso de un Handler?

Comment: @Elenasys buenas tardes, me podrías decir como y donde implementar lo que me sugieres, la verdad no tengo idea como hacer lo que me sugieres. gracias

Comment: ¿Alguien me puede ayudar con mi pregunta? por favor